# Error connecting to nodejs server cannot find node-restful

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server

i am working on an application that save my location on database via a nodejs server. Now i am working on server side and i am using express. When i start server and type nodemon server.js in terminal it shows me some error "cannot find symbol ..."

this is my status.js

```
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var statusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
latitudine: String,
longitudine: String,
imei: String
 });

//return models

const User = mongoose.model('User', statusSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

this is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//connect to mongodb:

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://tudorstanciulescu:19970826@test- 
srqul.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//route:

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

//start server:
app.listen(1000);

console.log('serverul porneste pe port 1000');
```

and this is my api.js

```
//dependencies

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//models

var Status = require('../models/status');

//routes

Status.methods(['get', 'post', 'put']);
Status.register(router, '/status');

//return router

module.exports = router;
```

the error i get 
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-restful'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ServerAplicatie\models\status.js:1:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ServerAplicatie\routes\api.js:8:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

i am new to nodejs and express so i don't understand how should i resolve this error

Comment: Have you installed it ([node-restful](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-restful))? `npm i -S node-restful`

Comment: thx, but it shows eror anyway D:\ServerAplicatie\node_modules\node-restful\lib\model.js:89
    delete self.routes[method];
                       ^ TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Please, post whole error stack-trace if possible... In another question. I guess this one is already resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to install [node-restful](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-restful) npm package.

Try:

```
npm i -S node-restful
```

Comment: yep, that was the answer, i didn't notice i forgot to install node-restful, thx you @Ihor